# Unable to save model with tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

When saving a model, in my case, HRNet, i met the following error:
ValueError: Unable to save the object ListWrapper([ListWrapper([None])])

Some of my layer looks like(Full version: https://github.com/zheLim/auto-face-parsing/blob/master/lib/model/hrnet_blocks.py):

```
class MultiResolutionLayer(layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, n_channels_list, bn_momentum=0.01, activation='relu'):
    """
    fuse feature from different branch with adding
    :param n_branches:
    :param n_channels:
    :param multi_scale_output:
    """
    super(MultiResolutionLayer, self).__init__()
    self.n_branches = len(n_channels_list)
    self.fuse_layers = [[] for branch_i in range(self.n_branches)]
    for branch_i in range(self.n_branches):
        layer = []
        for branch_j in range(self.n_branches):
            if branch_i < branch_j:
                # resolution of branch i is greater than branch_j
                # branch_j will be upsample with nearest resize
                layer.append(keras.Sequential(
                    [layers.Conv2D(filters=n_channels_list[branch_i], kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='same',
                                   use_bias=False, activation=activation),
                     layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum)]))
            elif branch_i == branch_j:
                # branch i is branch_j
                layer.append(None)
```

The error message suggest that "If you don't need this list checkpointed, wrap it in a tf.contrib.checkpoint.NoDependency object; it will be automatically un-wrapped and subsequently ignored." However, tf 2.0 has no contri module.
Any one knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I solved this problem, ...by switching to PyTorch

Comment: Check my answer in this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63069283/5814701
The same applies to a `list` attribute.